# select com multiplos BETWEENs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Boas gente,

preciso de uma ajuda, estou a fazer um filtro e para fazer o select eu fiz assim:

```html
$molcomp_query="SELECT * FROM stock_comp WHERE (diametroaco BETWEEN '$d1' and '$d2')
AND (comprimentototal BETWEEN '$comp1' AND '$comp2') 
AND (diametroexterior BETWEEN '$de1' AND '$de2') $ordenar_por";
```

mas está a dar erro nesta area:

```
if(isset($_POST)&&!empty($_POST)){ 
    if ($d1<>""){
        $d1=$_POST["d1"];
    }else{
        $d1=="0,200";
    }

    if ($d2<>""){
        $d1=$_POST["d2"];
    }else{
        $d2=="20";
    }

    if ($comp1<>""){
        $d1=$_POST["comp1"];
    }else{
        $comp1=="1";
    } 

    if ($comp2<>""){
        $d1=$_POST["comp2"];
    }else{
        $comp2=="10000";
    } 

    if ($de1<>""){
        $d1=$_POST["de1"];
    }else{
        $de1=="1";
    }

    if ($de2<>""){
        $d1=$_POST["de2"];
    }else{
        $de2=="200";
    }  
}
```

eu fiz assim para verificar se a caixa de texto do formulário não está vazia então a variável ficaria com o valor que o usuário inseriu, mas se estiver vazia a variável ficaria com um valor atribuído por mim, que é o mínimo e o máximo valor de cada um dos campos com alguma margem.

Comment: 'Between' serve apenas para consulta entre dois valores. Para consultar mais, utilize os simbolos de maior (>) e menor (<).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que seu *select* não seja o problema, você está usando *between* da maneira correta. Porém os *elses* não estão fazendo o que acredito que você pretenda.

Por exemplo, o primeiro está assim `$d1=="0,200";`, comparando ao invés de atribuir; isso deve estar refletindo na consulta.

Tente usar assim:

```
if(isset($_POST)&&!empty($_POST)){ 
    if ($d1<>""){
        $d1=$_POST["d1"];
    }else{
        $d1="0,200";
    }

    if ($d2<>""){
        $d1=$_POST["d2"];
    }else{
        $d2="20";
    }

    if ($comp1<>""){
        $d1=$_POST["comp1"];
    }else{
        $comp1="1";
    } 

    if ($comp2<>""){
        $d1=$_POST["comp2"];
    }else{
        $comp2="10000";
    } 

    if ($de1<>""){
        $d1=$_POST["de1"];
    }else{
        $de1="1";
    }

    if ($de2<>""){
        $d1=$_POST["de2"];
    }else{
        $de2="200";
    }  
}
```